# How to make gmail style profile menu in CSS?

Tags: css, angular, frontend

I would like to make a profile menu like in Gmail what contains the user's display name and his user name and also two buttons with settings and logout. I would like to make it in angular 8.

http://prntscr.com/q1vd8y

```
  <li>

        <!-- user profile -->
        <div class="profile">
          <img class="avatar"  src="" /><span></span>
          <!-- more menu -->
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="name">{{name}}</li>
            <li class="name">{{useremail}}</li>
            <li class="name">{{visiblename}}</li>
            <li><a href="={{url}}">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]='["/logout"]'>Log out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://material.io/design/

here it is, my friend, the one  and only, Material Design !
you can find css frameworks that will help you do it like

https://materializecss.com/

for example !

https://material.angular.io/ for angular